# Nginx puts browser into a redirect loop when using multiple server blocks

Tags: nginx, ssl, virtualhost, 301-redirect

I'm using Nginx to host a number of virtual hosts (or *server blocks* in Nginx nomenclature). These hosts all share the same domain with each assigned its own subdomain. One subdomain enters an endless redirect loop, obviously undesirable behavior.

**NB**: I've redacted my domain name and replaced it with `<mysite>`.

The root domain - `www.<mysite>.com` receives requests as expected. It also redirects HTTP requests to HTTPS. It is configured in `<mysite>-www`.

The subdomain `assets.<mysite>.com` also receives requests as expected. It isn't configured to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, either protocol is served. There is no trouble. It is configured in `<mysite>-holding`.

The final subdomain `soft.<mysite>.com` is configured identically to `assets.<mysite>.com` but it falters. It instead sends the browser on a redirect loop, each time pointing to `https://soft.<mysite>.com` This is despite there being no such setting in the config file for this vhost. It is configured in `<mysite>-soft`.

#### Config for `<mysite>-www`:

```
server {
    server_name www.<mysite>.com;

    listen 80 default_server ;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    root /var/www/html;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.<mysite>.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.<mysite>.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    root /var/www/html;
    server_name www.<mysite>.com;
    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location / {
        limit_req zone=mylimit burst=20 nodelay;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

#### Config for `<mysite>-holding`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name assets.<mysite>.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/assets.<mysite>.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/assets.<mysite>.com/privkey.pem; 
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    root /var/www/holding/html;

    location / {
        limit_req zone=mylimit burst=20 nodelay;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        index index.html;
    }
```

The config file for `soft.<mysite>.com` is identical to the one above, except for where it says 'assets' it says 'soft'. And yet it enters this endless redirect loop.

I've tried varying the location directive. I've consulted [the docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/web-server/) which were better than expected. Still, it loops. Help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the output of `nginx -T`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happened, the problem was as follows:

I hadn't symlinked properly from `/sites-enabled` to `/sites-available` and it was using an old duplicate of `<mysite>-www` which caused the redirect loop.

Having the file configured as above in my question was the solution. Either copying it to sites-enabled, or symlinking it properly will solve the problem for anyone in a similar predicament.

Mea culpa.

Comment: You should have a `default_server` virtual host that captures all the requests not matching any virtual server. It would reveal problems like this easier, it helps with Google duplicate content issues etc.